# Will a SHA1 Hash in C# always and forever return the same value for a given string?

Tags: c#, hash, sha1

I am considering changing the method whereby we encrypt passwords to use a one-way hash rather than an encryption.  I considered using a simple "GetHashCode" on the password string but MS warns that this function may change in the future and is different on 32 and 64-bit OSs.  I don't want the result to ever be different as this would result in all the passwords in the database no longer matching when I have the entered value (e.g. when we all move to .NET 9.0 or something).

So, does a SHA1 Hash eliminate this problem?  For example, if I use this C# code:

```
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        data = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

will the value always and forever be the same result?  I am not too worried about a collision in a space this big but is there any other reason to consider a wider hash?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: yeah sha1 md5 will remain constant... though sha1 and sha2 would be different,, Thats the main reason they exist!!

Comment: I recommend you switch to UTF8 encoding because ASCII will make you unhappy sooner or later. Also ASCII should die.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

Unlike GetHashCode, SHA-1 is a fixed algorithm, just like MD5 and SHA-256,
all of which have been "standardized".

Comment: Although I'd imagine 2 different strings could have the same hash. Seems reasonable, no?

Comment: @Esteban: Yes, that is one of the fundamental principles of information theory. There are an infinite number of strings but only 2^256 256-bit numbers, so there *must* be repeats. The bigger your hash result, the lower your chances of finding two strings with the same hash code.

Comment: @Esteban, yes but you're more likely to get hit by a bus after you win the lottery (exaggerating obviously) especially with sha512 or sha2

Comment: @Jesus: Actually, that's not an exaggeration at all. The odds of getting hit by a bus after winning the lottery are only around one in 2 to the 60 or so. The odds of randomly getting a hash collision with a 256 bit crypto hash are about a trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion times *less* likely than that. (If you are *deliberately* looking for a collision -- either a hash collision or a bus collision -- the odds are of course completely different.)

Comment: Thanks @Peter.  I'm not worried about collisions at all as this is a basic password hash in a database that is already highly secure.  The clients just want to be sure that passwords that their people enter cannot be read by anyone on our side just in case they use the same passwords elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  SHA1 is a standard, and the C# implementation must conform to the standard and produce the same results.

For your information, SHA1 is not a very good way to hash passwords, although it's certainly a big improvement over reversible encryption.  SHA1, like MD5, is designed to hash a lot of data very fast, so it's very amenable to brute-force password cracking.  The best hash functions for passwords are designed to be (relatively) slow or have adjustable speed and are hard to accelerate with hardware.  One which is built into the .NET framework is PBKDF2, which essentially implements "stretched" SHA1 (applying SHA1 over and over to the same input so that it takes longer.)  It's implemented in [this framework class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)